# Notification с кастомной разметкой, не могу менять состояние кнопок

Tags: android, android-notification, android-button

Столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу менять состояние у Button из кастомной разметки в Notification.

```
Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
playIntent.setAction(Constants.PLAY);
PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, playIntent, 0);

Intent pauseIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
pauseIntent.setAction(Constants.PAUSE);
PendingIntent ppauseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, pauseIntent, 0);

Intent repeatIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
repeatIntent.setAction(Constants.REPEAT);
PendingIntent prepeatIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, repeatIntent, 0);

Intent repeatOffIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
repeatOffIntent.setAction(Constants.REPEAT_OFF);
PendingIntent prepeatOffIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, repeatOffIntent, 0);

Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
closeIntent.setAction(Constants.STOP);
PendingIntent pcloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, closeIntent, 0);

contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);

contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.titleNot, "Music");
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textNot, "Track 1");

contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.playNot, pplayIntent);
contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.repeatNot, prepeatIntent);
contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.stopNot, pcloseIntent);

contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.playNot, R.drawable.ic_action_play);
contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.repeatNot, R.drawable.ic_action_repeat);
contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.stopNot, R.drawable.ic_action_stop);

notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setContent(contentView)
                .setOngoing(true).build();

notification.contentIntent = pplayIntent;
notification.contentIntent = prepeatIntent;
notification.contentIntent = pcloseIntent;

startForeground(Constants.FOREGROUND_ID, notification);
```

У меня три кнопки, мне нужно чтобы с нажатием на кнопку плей воспроизводился трек, и с повторным нажатием происходила пауза, на данный момент с нажатием только плей происходит. Что касается медиа плеера, то им я могу управлять, а что касается состояния кнопки, то я не могу ее менять. Как один из вариантов я видел пример с заменой разметки, но хотелось бы без этого, если такое возможно.

Comment: Попробуйте так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16435330/3212712

Comment: Хотелось бы пример с кастомной разметкой.

Comment: Вот, вроде: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30771421/3212712

Comment: Попытался из этого сообразить, не смог, там условие в версиях апи, если одна версия грузится одна разметка, если версия другая, грузится другая. А моя проблема именно в кнопках, я не знаю какое условие сделать, чтобы когда плеер будет воспроизведен кнопка плей становилась кнопкой пауза и наоборот.

Comment: Не обращайте внимания на версии. Смотрите на метод `updateNotif` - там показано, как обновить изображение кнопки - фишка в использовании того же билдера для апдейта уведомления что и при его создании.

Comment: Нет, все равно не добился ничего.

Comment: Других ссылок у меня нет(